# Content porter to same level of publication - CMS Tridion

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

We have 03 main publication and then 04a,04b,04c,04d translated publication . Our requirement is to copy all translated content from 04a and copy into 04e at same level. Can we do this through content porter . Where all i need to change mapping.xml to do this.

I have a idea to change the webdev path of intermediate package to point 04e and import it.

Please suggest .

Comment: This sounds like it would be better Blueprinted, i.e. 04e using 04a as a parent publication?  If not, what are you trying to achieve with the copy (i.e. once copied, what changes will be made to the content?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it is not possible to copy across publications, Just By renaming the publications for your operations you can do this. Mapping xml is also the option for this but renaming seems to be more comfartable.

```
1.Rename 04a --> temp
2.Create Content Porter Package
3.Rename temp --> 04a
4.Rename 04e --> temp
5.Import package in to temp
6.Rename temp -->04e
```

For Editing of Mappings XML click on highlighted Edit button which will open the mappings XML. You need to update importContext and importTitle attributes in this file which are by default empty.  I would suggest the renaming of publication as it is less error prone. 
 [image]

Comment: Alok,Can you share the mapping.xml details as well because 04a is inherited by 10 more publications at 07 level...so it will be a very big risk to do that .

Comment: I have tried editing the mappings xml once but got errors while porting. So you need to work out how to correctly update mappings xml

Comment: Alok,this mapping open a temporary file in temp folder.I am talking about the mapping file in intermediate package .

Comment: Jitender, Both of these xmls are same. You can just go to your IF Package and edit mappings xml.

Comment: +1 on renaming before import or export approach - I've used this one in the past quite successfully

Comment: Nuno,Is there any risk in renaming approach if 04a is used in 10 more publication at 07 level ? Just want to make sure it doesn't break my current publications

Comment: I have tried this on my development server and it works fine for a bunch of components .Just addition to the above question.Will it break anything in my existing 04a publication regarding translation,checked out status.

Comment: there is never a risk in renaming a Publication, unless you have some functionality which depends on that name. Renaming a Publication temporarily for export/import purposes will have no effect what so ever on any of your other Publications.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, i have tried this on my development server and it works perfectly .

Answer (score 2):

I agree the rename is easier. Editing mappings.xml doesn't seem to be popular in my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11482824/395495), but also see post from [Monica Manzano](http://monicamanzano.blogspot.com/2012/12/moving-items-around-within-single.html) and a rant from [Dominic Cronin](http://www.cronin.nl/weblog/from-the-horses-mouth...-a-hot-content-portering-tip-and-a-bit-of-a-rant) also describing the renaming approach.

### Mappings.xml

The `mappings.xml` file is documented on SDL Live Content for recent Content Porter versions.

- [Content Porter SP2](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_ContentPorter_2009_SP2/concept_BF79F0D0D89B4A2787CF12D628C0A21D) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))
- [Content Porter SP1](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_ContentPorter_2009_SP2/concept_BF79F0D0D89B4A2787CF12D628C0A21D)
- See [TridionWorld](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/) ([requires login](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/about/access/index.aspx)) for older versions.

### Format

Note the URL-escaped paths in the following example  (Content Porter 2009 up to SP1):

```xml
<tcccp:Mapping
  exportContext="/Publication/Building%20Blocks"
  exportTitle="component.xml"
  importContext="/Destination%20%Pub"
  importTitle="" />
```

*IMO, it's worth doing the "official" way at least once (then we could [get feedback to the right people](http://ideas.sdltridion.com)). :-)*

**Edit**: formatted XML into separate lines. My mappings.xml had this on one line.

Comment: That was a pretty good rant, too... back in 2008. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off with looking into a blueprint solution, but the trick is to rename publication 4a into "temp port pub", do the export, undo the publication name change, now change 4e into "temp port pub", do the import, and undo the publication name change.