# Moving components/folders from child publication to parent publication without breaking its dependencies

Tags: 2011, blueprint

I have some components wrongly created in some child publications. I would like to move these components to parent publication with out breaking the dependencies in the pages.

Do we have any power tool doing the same job.

Comment: Have whoever created them in the wrong publication create them again in the right one, and re-link into the pages again, before deleting the old components - the frustration at having to do this will pretty much guarantee that they never make this mistake again ;o)

Comment: I actually agree with Will here. The issue seems to be education (and punishment!) fix the root cause and not just resolve it technically. If it's 200 components - it's a punch and a technical solution; if it's <25 components - make them do it and learn a valuable lesson or the tool will just hide an issue of use.

Comment: I've had colleagues suggest a higher threshold of 100 items (under 100 means authors get to do it). :-) A kindler approach is to remove write options from the children publications or remove scope if the authors shouldn't see those publications at all. Good mantra for authors: "what publication am I in?"

Comment: Oh and if you have Experience Manager, Page Types, Content Types, and XPM's context settings will reduce this as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do this you would have to use the content porter tool.

Export your content from the cms, when importing you can manage the mapping of the publications.

I've personally had trouble with it in the past so I typically modify the package to change the WebDAV paths for the dependencies.  Do so with extreme caution though :)

Be aware that if the child components exist you may need to be moved or removed before you import.

**UPDATE:**
There is also an old powertool that let you copy / move items from one publication to another, i'd recommend checking it out, you may need to do some work to get the tool working in 2011.

Comment: Thank you for answer. If the components are used in pages, in that I also need to import and export pages also right.

Comment: potentially export pages and components as two different exports, if you can remove the pages, then fix issues with components, the re import the pages, ensuring the component dependencies are correct. - very tricky and be very careful of how you achieve this.

Comment: The hardest part of using the Mapping.xml is likely the encoding and choosing the right paths. [I've done it](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/2194/46) (but it's not that fun). Exporting pages would actually be a good idea, that way you can copy them from below when done, rather than having to re-wire them. The move part after the export is important (otherwise CP will complain about the path conflict). Start with a single page and its components to test, you'll be fine.

Comment: Update: Anton Minko demystifies the mapping file: http://tridioninternals.blogspot.com/2014/02/manual-mappings-demystified-publication.html. I take back my "not that fun" comment. :-)