# How to move items from one publication to another publication within same CME

Tags: content-porter-2013

I've already tried renaming a Publication before and after import/export using the Content Porter but every time it shows some kind of error because of the Blueprint hierarchy. Are there any settings I can change in Content Porter during Export or Import?

Comment: Hi Rahul - Welcome to stackexchange! Can you add more details to your question like version of Tridion? I am assuming that you are using content porter since you tagged it :). If you are using content porter, you can change the mapping during the import and also do some changes in the IF package to avoid conflicts.. Take a back up before the import so that you do something that you do not intend to do! Refer John's answer here http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/moving-components-folders-from-child-publication-to-parent-publication-without-b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Content Porter is really for moving content from one environment to
  another.
- The challenge with moving items from one publication to another is
  the dependencies: a component in publication 050 may have a component link to an image that is *also* in 050. So you have to move the image from 050 to 030, and *then* move the component.

It's not a perfect solution, but there is a bookmarklet that allows you to copy and paste from one *open* component to another in the same CME: http://blog.frankmtaylor.com/2015/04/06/copy-and-paste-components-across-publications-in-tridion/

first, drag the the bookmarklet into your bookmarks bar... then:

1. Open the component which you want to move
2. Open a blank component in the new publication, with the schema set
3. In the window with the open component, click the bookmarklet
4. in the window with the blank component, click the bookmarklet again

Caveats:

- This will not resolve component links (which, again, is why you can't move
  components up and down the blueprint); it'll only work with text content that doesn't have any component links of any kind.
- This was developed and tested on Tridion 2013 SP1 in Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

The other option for such movement could be a custom implementation where you request your source and destination details and then using **core service**, update the details.

> By using core service, you have to full control over properties that
>   you want to set and properties that you want to ignore.